# Is chicken of a foreign restaurent halal?

Tags: halal-haram, food, travelling

I am living in a foreign country and some times for industrial tour I have to travel here. In that case I have to take food from a foreign restaurant where they might not take the name of Allah while slaughtering the chicken. I also don't know how they are slaughtering it. Can I have that chicken in that case? Some times I found they do not have any fish item or any other kind of halal items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zibah on the name of ghair ullah is haram, If you have nothing else to eat and other muslim restaurants are too far and you have no way to go and get their you can eat it. 
As per saheeh hadith Haram food can only be consumed if you fear of dying of hunger. So consider or compare your situation.

So in your case better thing todo is to goto halal meat shop buy meat in bulk prep it with spices and freez it and consume it periodically (you can bake or fry it youtube is full of such recipies) to make sure you are eating Halal. 
Rest Allah knows best.